# Impossible to return a list / collection of projection

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-rest, projection

I made a spring-boot project to access to my datas.

My main class is Patient.java:

```
@Entity
public class Patient {
    private Long id;
    private String numeroSs;
    private String profession;
// lot of stuff...., getters, setters, ...
}
```

In order to improve my requests, I've made a very simple projection of my class Patient. I've called this projection PatientCustom :

```
public interface PatientCustom {
     String getNumeroSs();
     Timestamp getDateProchainRdv();
}
```

And in my repository "PatientRepo.java", I created two custom methods :

```
@Transactional
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "patient", path = "patient")
public interface PatientRepo extends JpaRepository<Patient, Long> {
    PatientCustom findOneByNumeroSs(String numeroSs);
    Collection<PatientCustom> findByNumeroSs(String numeroSs);
}
```

When I use the first method, no problem : it returns a PatientCustom :

```
{
numeroSs: "150505617017002",
dateProchainRdv: null
}
```

But When I want a list or a collection, it sends me an error :

```
{
cause: null,
message: "Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165!"
}
```

And the traces in my terminal :

```
2019-03-12 10:32:34.671 ERROR 2072 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
```

I understand very well that spring wants to add a proxy class to my interface, but when it want to add this proxy to a list or a collection, it's unhappy because list and collection are not interfaces but classses.

What can I do to solve this ?